# Permission denied starting Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, file-permissions

I just installed Indigo (Eclipse) on my ubuntu 11.10 machine and received a permission denied error when attempting to start Eclipse from the terminal.

```
ls -l /usr/lib/ | grep eclipse
```

yields

```
drwxr-sr-x  9 root ben          4096 2011-10-13 12:10 eclipse_indigo
```

I tried to `sudo chmod 755 eclipse_indigo` to no avail.
Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
strace /usr/lib/eclipse_indigo
```

yields

```
execve("/usr/lib/eclipse_indigo/", ["/usr/lib/eclipse_indigo/"], [/* 74 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcabfef8000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "strace: exec: Permission denied\n", 32strace: exec: Permission denied
) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fcabfef8000, 4096)            = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Comment: Before changing any permissions (restore the original permissions of that directory to the old state, it was intentipnal that way), try to find the reason. What command are you trying? Show the `ls -l` of that command. Maybe a `strace` with that command.

Comment: @ott-- added the strace to the post. Thanks.

Comment: /usr/lib/eclipse_indigo is a directory, not an executable file. Isn't there something with eclipse in /usr/bin? `ls -l /usr/bin/*eclipse*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's better if you just extract the tar.gz file** from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux **in your home directory** and use it from there...

I did the same... just wait till you need to install plugins for it. Even if you manage to start it you'll have other issues, so extract the archive and save yourself from some headaches...

Comment: Definitely the easiest solution with the least drawbacks. And I do use plug-ins so this should really help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to install using your user instead of root?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo chown ben:ben eclipse_indigo` to set yourself as the owner as well as the group-owner.  I think your problem is related to that `r-s` in the group perms field of eclipse_indigo, unless that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a linux machine, where eclipse was unpacked as root and started by a regular user.

Be careful, not to start eclipse as root, as it does an initialization of the so-called confguration directory inside your installation.

You may find my answer to that question useful (includes steps to fix it up):
[Unable to open Eclipse (configuration area .. error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336470/unable-to-open-eclipse-configuration-area-error/20842066#20842066)