# Unable to open Eclipse (configuration area .. error)

Tags: eclipse, file-permissions

When try to start my Eclipse I am getting the following error:

> The configuration area at '/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration' could not
>   be created. Please choose a writable location

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: I think that just moving the "eclipse" directory to somewhere your user can write should be enough. Try to move the folder, for instance, to your home ;)

Answer (score 2):

Open `/Users/{Your_Dir_Name}/.eclipse`; right click on `.eclipse`,then change permission read-only to read and `w`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a linux machine, where eclipse was unpacked as root and started by a regular user.

This kind of setup is call "shared install" (see [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html)).

You will encounter problems, if you run/ran your eclipse as root, as in this case, a "private install" is assumed and the **configuration** directory is so-called **initialized**.

The **solution** is, to restore (revert) the configuration structure from the inital tar.gz/zip-package. Here, is a sample dir structure from Eclipse Kepler, mainly consisting of a config.ini file:

```
configuration/
configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator
configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
configuration/config.ini
configuration/org.eclipse.update
configuration/org.eclipse.update/platform.xml
```

After restoring the files, you can start over and execute eclipse from an regular user account.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

Or leave it there but make your changes using elevated privileges (sudo).  My Eclipse install is in /opt but I did a lot of the work at the command line using sudo and I had to change the Eclipse folder to be owned by root. (and all of the sub folders as well).  But it works great.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse install area should probably be either writeble by you or not. If it is, then it will use that configuration directory. If not, then it will use the configuration directory it creates in your home directory.

If the eclipse install area is writable by you, but its configuration directory is not, then you may get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window, type: `cd /usr/lib/eclipse`

Run Eclipse as superuser/root:
`sudo ./eclipse`

When you get a prompt asking for WORKSPACE DIRECTORY, change it to you own workspace, rather than root's.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your disk quota was exceeded, I faced the same issue and tried all the suggestions on this thread.

Finally, I found out that the disk free space was 0.

Hope that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this error message is an outdated (or broken) User Shell Folder configuration at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Desktop that Java uses to set the user.home path variable. You will find out that your current %USERPROFILE% has a value of C:\User[username] or any other value like C:\User[username].MYDOMAIN, but not the path C:\User[username].MYDOMAIN.000

Open cmd and run the following command.

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Desktop" /t REG_SZ /d "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" /f
```